# @media only screen resolution height issues

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design

I am trying to align a bottom bar that is in homepage footer of my website. I want to adjust it so it will look good on common screen resolutions.

I have an issue with these resolutions 1280x960 and 1280x1024

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:960px){
    .tp-caption.black, .black {
        margin-top: 496px!important;
    }
```

And then use this code after that

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) and (min-height:961px){
    .tp-caption.black, .black {
        margin-top: 464px!important;
    }
```

The issue is it uses the same css, for both resolutions. 1280x960 media query

also applied in 1280x1024 resolution.

It displays the 2nd media query css code in browser, but ignores it and take

the above query.

I want to set the margin for both resolutions, for both heights 960 & 1024.

Can someone please explain me how to fix this?

Comment: never tried this but you could try nesting your media queries - an outer one for the max-width and put the max heights inside that

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same in fiddle, this works fine. 
jsfiddle.net/5wx9qqyq/3/

One possible cause can be, missing closing braces for
@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) and (max-height:960px){ **}**

Please verify.